# what is considered an instance in windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

If I have a handful of tasks scheduled that execute the same .exe file but have different parameters, are they all considered the same instance or different?

One of these tasks failed with output 0x41301 "task is already running"

tasklist /V shows each as separate PID if I run them manually in a cmd window.

So I changed all my tasks that trigger the same .exe but different params to "queue a new instance" if one is already running. However I'm not sure what is considered an instance, the entire command with parameters or just the executable?

Comment: Have you created multiple tasks or a single task with multiple actions?

Comment: multiple tasks with same .exe but different parameters.